# Should I clear Prius ODB-II codes?

Tags: toyota, obd-ii, prius

My 2015 Prius had been sitting for several months without being started. The starter battery went flat so when I turned it on, the dash turned on and off in a loop.

I charged the starter battery to full, and tried again. “Hybrid system error, see dealer”. The hybrid system indeed doesn’t run, only the ICE engine runs when I drive it.

There are many ODB-II codes, which I have exported to a file. But the only pending, confirmed, failing test is: P602F(46) ECM “eeprom error”.

I am wondering if it is okay to clear all these codes, since I imagine the low starter battery voltage (and multiple cycles) really confused the electronics.

Could clearing possibly fix the issue, or is that wishful thinking? Should I clear, or take it to the dealer as is?

**Followup:**

After I had recharged the starter battery, I exported the codes to a file in case I needed them later. Then I cleared all the codes and restarted the car. Great news, the hybrid system is working perfectly again, and no codes have returned. (I'll update this question again if I regret this down the line!)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 7):

The first thing I do when checking any vehicle is to clear the codes, that way I can see what comes back up afterwards. Those are the codes you look to see what issues the car might have. So "should you"? IMHO, yes.

Most likely, clearing the codes won't fix your issues. All it's going to do is point more directly to what actually the problem might be. Especially since it's saying there's an EEPROM error. That sounds like there's an issue with computer which runs the hybrid system.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I just wanted to make sure I wasn’t going to make things harder for the dealership if I do need to eventually take it in. Sounds like real issues will continue to be reported as code though. Thanks

Comment: I think that clearing the codes would be a bad idea if you plan on taking it to the dealer. They may be able to utilize the information to come to a more accurate diagnosis. Now if you were going to try and diagnose this yourself, you could record the codes and types and clear them as Paulster2 said.

Comment: @Jupiter - The codes that clear are irrelevant. If they don't come back, why look at them.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 My understanding is that some codes will occur only during certain conditions.  Thus, if you clear codes that only occur during those conditions, and then take the vehicle to a mechanic, they will have no idea that such conditions occurred.  This will make it much harder for them to diagnose issues that only occur in specific conditions.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket As a software engineer who's previously worked on ECMs, I can confirm that this is correct. Also faults caused by loose wiring /connections may genuinely go away temporarily if the connection is made temporarily, and this will happen when the car is stationary and you're looking at it; but they'll tend to come back when the car starts moving and knocks the connection.

Comment: @Graham Thanks for the confirmation Graham.  Temperatures play a large role too, as can variations in fuel, oil, and road conditions.  I'm sure you know much more than I do, but I've wondered if basic ODB-II readers display just the top-level codes, but some manufacturers sell much more comprehensive readers to mechanics/dealers that provide further details... actually that's an interesting question... I'll ask it... https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/93954/do-odb-ii-eodb-jodb-readers-for-dealers-mechanics-show-more-than-consumer-reader

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket - If you clear the codes and they do not come back, they are a non-event. The big thing the codes do not tell you is *when they happen*. Part of the reason to clear the codes is to see which codes are valid right now. As a mechanic, if you go trying to diagnose codes which are no longer valid, you are chasing your tail. You need to get on to the meat of the issue(s) otherwise you are just wasting time. Clearing the codes and seeing what comes back is a first step in diagnosing those issues.

Comment: Yes, when doing a diagnosis, clearing can be very beneficial. But if you are leaving the vehicle to be diagnosed by someone else, the information that was cleared would have been crucial in a good mechanics tool belt for a better and quicker diagnosis. Most mechanics upon hearing that the customer had cleared the codes are thinking and many times saying to the customer that they shouldn't clear them.

Comment: @Jupiter - I'm suggesting getting rid of stale codes. Stale codes provide no added benefit for diagnostics. In fact, clearing stale codes can and do actually help with diagnostics, because stale codes are misleading. Also, when a battery goes bad, as is suggested by the OP, it tends to throw a bunch of irrelevant codes. These irrelevant codes can lead a mechanic down the wrong path. Clearing the irrelevant codes helps lead you to the proper diagnosis faster. When you are working by the job, the faster you get done that job done, the better for your pocket book.

Comment: @Jupiter - Also, if a vehicle is still under warranty, the dealership is obligated to fix the car regardless of whether the codes have been cleared. I personally could care less what a mechanic thinks about whether the codes have been cleared or not. I'd suggest to anyone else they shouldn't either.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 wrote *If you clear the codes and they do not come back, they are a non-event.* Obviously, I disagree, but I don't want to get in a long debate/discussion. If an engine only throws codes on hot or humid days, but it hasn't been hot or humid in weeks, I still want to know about it.  And I don't want to wait for another hot/humid day to find out there is a problem and get stuck when the weather is at its worst.  Same for codes that that only appear in freezing weather, etc.

Comment: What I am picking up is that it's probably a case-by-case kind of thing. If you are having a crack at fixing your vehicle, and have good reason to think you have fixed what caused the codes (as in my case), clearing them seems like it could give you great information. As @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 correctly explained, my flat battery caused a huge number of junk codes that really made no sense at all. Also, in my case, clearing the "pending" code actually resolved my problem. I can easily imagine other scenarios where clearing codes would make things worse, including increasing the size of your repair bill.

Comment: Just in case it went under the radar, clearing this code actually fixed the issue. I think the hybrid system went into a persistent fault state (like a "safe mode") out of an abundance of caution. Clearing the code seemingly gave it permission to try running normally again, which seems to be fine.

Comment: @aaaidan - That's awesome, if not completely unexpected. The easy fixes are always the best fixes :o)